# past simple or present in this case: "It would be nice to see you before I leave (left)."

Tags: backshifting, wish

I am going on holidays in two days for two weeks, but before going I would like to see my friend: shall I say

> It would be nice to see you before I **leave**.
>
> It would be nice to see you before I **left**.

I think the second one is better, as it is not a real situation but a wish.

Comment: The second one probably sounds better to your ear because it is using the default **backshift** version, where it is using the past-tense verb "left".

Comment: There are 3 main uses of the past-tense verb: 1. past time, 2. modal remoteness, 3. backshift. Your second example involves backshift. When backshift is available (as it is in your example), it is usually optional, and usually it is considered to be the default (which means that it is usually preferred).

Comment: @F.E. - so the second sentence is grammatical? Very interesting! I thought one needed a reported speech clause or a later past event mentioned to implement backshifting.

Comment: @CopperKettle Yes, for the matrix clause verb "would" is a past-tense, and that makes backshift available. Usually, the backshift version ("left") would be used here. Though, there's nothing wrong with the first version. Either version is fine. The first version (the non-backshift) might be considered to be slightly marked, and so, would probably be used in a situation where a superior is requesting a junior to be available for a, er, chat before the superior leaves.

Comment: @CopperKettle Reported speech is a subset of backshift. To make backshift available for a subordinate clause, there's basically two conditions, and at least one of those two has to be fulfilled: 1. a superordinate clause is headed by a past-tense verb, 2. the situation involves the past. If one or both are fulfilled, then backshift is available and it is usually the default.

Comment: So, "It would be nice" is past tense? How would you say that in present tense?

Comment: To me the second sentence sounds distinctly ungrammatical. I can understand "I would have liked to see you before I left." or "I would like to see you before I leave". The thing is "I would like to see you ..." is not past tense in this as far as I can tell. The speaker would like to see that someone now/at some time in the future but before he leaves. If you use "left" I believe it must be actually in the past so for example "I knew I would like to see you before I left." works.

Comment: @F.E. -  A native speaker **[here](http://lang-8.com/1017887/journals/181606313849522082875555630116466459409)** has said that option 1 seemed more natural to them. I hope some native speaker writes an authoritative answer.

Comment: @CopperKettle As a native speaker, I will say that "left" sounds wrong to me. If you said "It would have been nice to see you before I left." That would be correct but in the exact sentence above, I would use "leave" every time.

Comment: *Left* and *leave* both sound fine to me, personally.  I find it interesting that some speakers feel so strongly about option #2 sounding ungrammatical.

Comment: @snailboat - It would be nice to see your answer to this question posted before the bounty period expired. Or is it "expires"? (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle It appears that you already have a handle on this, w.r.t. backshift. You might also want to look into extraposition, as that seems to also be involved. :)

Comment: @CopperKettle Wut?! Wut?! Where be them 300 bonus points? Them all gone! Gone ah tell ya! No longer available for new answer posts! You had a couple of more days left! *sniffle, sniffle!* Ya never know what potential answer posts are out there in the wild. And now, with no fresh carcass to lure them in, er, what was I talking about?, er, well, anyhow. :)

Comment: @F.E. Yea. The guerdon's gone. Not totally nathless, for it now emblazons Shoe's escutcheon. (0:

Comment: @DRF,when you say you consider "I would have liked to see you before I left" grammatical, do you only mean for when the reference time is the past, or also for when the reference time is still the future like in the "I would like to ..." version, but the speaker's wish to see the listener before leaving has been thwarted?

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed Even in the case where the wish was thwarted. So if I'm calling someone before I leave for my vacation and they tell me they can't stop by before I leave for some reason, saying "That's a shame. I would have liked to see you before I left." sounds alright to me. As I point out in my profile though, I have spent a long time in English speaking countries (US) including some formative years for language, but I'm not a native speaker by birth.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OP believes that *It would be nice to see you before I left* expresses a wish and not a real situation, and this is why the past tense is better in the subordinate clause.

It is certainly true that wishes that a present situation were different are commonly expressed in the past tense:

> I wish I **had** more money.

It is also true that the past tense is typically used in the subordinate clauses of similar (so-called) conditional 2 sentences to express an unreal (counterfactual) situation:

> It would be nice if I **had** more money.

The past tense is also used in conditional 2 sentences to convey the speaker's belief in the remoteness of the possibility of something happening:

> It would be nice if I finally **won** some money on the lottery.

Further, the past tense is common (but far from mandatory) in the subordinate clauses of reported statements:

> She said that it would be nice to see you before you **left**.

But none of the above contexts fits the OP's example. The *It would be nice to see you* clause in this context does not mandate the past  tense of the verb in the subordinate clause.

The leaving is prearranged, hence the present tense is used. There is nothing unreal or counterfactual or reported about the leaving. The present tense is the usual tense for scheduled events: cf. *My plane leaves at 8.45 tomorrow evening*. So, my clear preference in this context is for:

> It would be nice to see you before I **leave**.

Two further points. Firstly, the main clause can be expanded to:  *It would be nice if I **could** see you* .. , in which case the past tense (*could*) is used to express a wish, remote possibility or counterfactual. But this still has no influence of the tense in the *before I leave* clause.

Secondly, the past tense is often used to express deference or politeness. For example:

> Excuse me, I **wanted** to see the manager. Is she free?

So, *It would be nice to see you before I **left*** is conceivable in the context of, for example, a student requesting an appointment with a professor.

---

*Addendum*

The list below shows the Google results for various "*It would be [ nice / good / great ] to  [verb] ... before  I  ...* " constructions. They show that the present tense is much more usual in the *before* clauses of such constructions.

> - It would be nice / good / great to see you before I leave  [14]
> - It would  be nice / good / great to see you before I left   [0]

> - It would be nice / good / great to see you before I go [10]
> - It would be nice / good / great to see you before I went    [1]

> - It would be nice / good / great to know before I leave [4]
> - It would be nice / good / great to know before I left   [1]

> - It would be nice / good / great to know before I go [40]
> - It would be nice / good / great to know before I went   [0]

Comment: "It would be nice to see you before you left" alone sounds weird, but with preceding context that fleshes things out a bit better, it can sound OK.  "I will be gone for two weeks on vacation.  It would be nice to see you before I left."  That sounds fine.

Comment: @ultrasawblade. Yes, the past tense does not sound unnatural in the context you mention. The problem on this site is that we are often asked, as here, to comment on the acceptability of decontextualised sentences without any knowledge of the speaker's communicative intent. As Lewis in _The English Verb_ (p83) states: " _... any attempt to describe certain grammatical choices objectively is doomed to failure. Account needs to be taken of the centrality of the speaker._"

Comment: @ultrasawblade - I wonder why would the addition of "I will be gone for two weeks on vacation" make "before I *left*" more acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I believe both are fine.

The first one is definitely much more natural because most people don't want to use past tense for something that has not happened yet.

But the second one is **not** wrong because in English past tense is used for polite expressions.  Here's an article from British Council that might convince you:  http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/past-tense

And for more examples:  http://blog.harwardcommunications.com/2014/07/30/how-to-be-polite/

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "would be" is *not* past tense in that sentence, rather, it is a conditional expressing contingency or possibility.  For that reason, the *first sentence* is correct:

> It would be nice to see you before I **leave**.

This sounds the most natural.

References here:

- http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/writing/grammar/parts_of_speech/verbs.htm
- http://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs-will-would-shall-should.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my view only the first sentence makes sense. The speaker has not left yet, so a past-tense is confusing. This is no case for backshift.

Added: The sentence has the same meaning as "I would like to see you before I leave".

Answer (score 0):

I post this as an answer because long comments are usually discouraged in SE.

I've asked a similar question [Tense simplification in the present or future irrealis conditionals,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28932/tense-simplification-in-the-present-or-future-irrealis-conditionals) which I think could be of some help.

As StoneyB correctly puts it, those past forms mark all the sentences as irrealis. That's also why you prefer your second example.

However, let's take a closer look.

Compare:

> It would be nice to see you before I left.

with the PEU examples:

> If I had lots of money, I would give some to anybody who asked for it.
>
> Would you follow me wherever I went?

You can only give money to someone after being asked for it.

You can only follow me after knowing where I'm heading.

But I will not be able to see you after I leave. Note that the departure has been predetermined, and it's only the meeting that is hypothetical.